# Parsing unescaped HTML and retrieving tag values with the XML library

Tags: r, xpath, xml-parsing, escaping, html-parsing

I am using the R package XML to load and parse an HTML page. I can successfully navigate to the snippets I want using XPath. However the HTML pages in question do not seem to use escaped characters. As an example consider the following HTML code:

```
<tr>
  <td width=\"50%\"><font size=\"1\" face=\"Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif\">MnO</font></td>
  <td width=\"50%\" align=\"right\"><font size=\"1\" face=\"Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif\">
         <0.05 % <BR>
               </font>
  </td>
</tr>
```

Notice how we have a "<0.05 %" instead of a  `"&lt;0.05 %"`. When I parse the document all I get back are two "\r\n". The only solution I see right now is to search for and substitute such substrings. I have tried to load the file in various ways to see if we could "reverse" escape the document but have not succeeded. I have also looked for some parsing option that would consider such un-escaped characters but have not found any.

Does anyone know of a way to handle this in a general fashion. If not, how would you solve this.

Note: I think that the XML package uses the libxml C library.

**EDIT**: an example can be found here:

http://rop.ineti.pt/rop/FormProduto.php?idProduto=166

(see bottom right table with chemical composition)

Comment: Can you provide the URL of the page you want to parse?

Comment: See the link I provided in the new edit. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Does the following help?  I did NOT use the gsub() calls to clean up the list, but you might find them helpful.  Also, it is possible your language encoding is different than mine (English).

```
table <- readHTMLTable("http://rop.ineti.pt/rop/FormProduto.php?idProduto=166", useInternal = TRUE)
```

# table <- gsub("^[[:alnum:]|[:space:]|[:ascii:]]$", "", perl = TRUE, table) # if not alnum, space or ascii, empty string; punct?
   # table <- gsub("[[:punct:]]", "", perl = TRUE, table)
   # table <- gsub("\n|\t|\r", "", perl = TRUE, table)

```
table[20]

> table[20]
$`NULL`
           Al2O3 14.64 %
1            CaO  0.58 %
2  Fe2O3 (total)  1.44 %
3           H2O+  0.78 %
4           H2O-  0.05 %
5            K2O  4.89 %
6            MgO  0.17 %
7            MnO        
8           Na2O  3.45 %
9           P2O5  0.45 %
10          SiO2 73.23 %
11          TiO2  0.24 %
```

Comment: If you look at the entry for 'MnO' you will see their is no value. It has the value '<0.05 %' (see HTML snippet above), yet nothing is obtained. This is exactly what I was getting. I suspect this is because the '<' has not been escaped.

Comment: Perhaps there is no "answer" then, if the underlying HTML is done oddly or incorrectly.  Xpath expressions then fall short.  Anyway, I tried.